# Read and Store text file with string and float data into a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, filereader

I have a text file and each line in the ﬁle starts with a word followed by 50 ﬂoating point numbers that represent the word’s vector description (the embedding). I am trying to  read the ﬁle and store each word and its embedding in a hash table. The problem that I am facing is that I get a Number Format Exception or sometimes an array out of bounds exception. How can I read and store each word and its embedding in a hash map?

sNode class:

```
public class sNode{ // Node class for hash map
public String word; 
public float[] embedding; 
public sNode next;

public sNode(String S, float[] E, sNode N){ // Constructor
    word = S; 
    embedding = new float[50];
    for (int i=0;i<50;i++) 
        embedding[i] = E[i]; next = N; 
}
```

hashTableStrings class:

```
public class hashTableStrings{ 
private static sNode [] H;
private int TABLE_SIZE;
private int size; 

public hashTableStrings(int n){ // Initialize all lists to null H = new sNode[n]; for(int i=0;i<n;i++) H[i] = null; }
    size = 0;
    TABLE_SIZE = n;
    H = new sNode[TABLE_SIZE]; 
    for(int i=0;i<TABLE_SIZE;i++) 
        H[i] = null;
}

public int getSize(){ // Function to get number of key-value pairs
    return size;
}


public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("glove.6B.50d.txt"));

    HashMap<String, Float> table = new HashMap<String, Float>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split("\t\t"); // split space between word and float number embedding
        for (int i=0; i<50;i++){
            table.put(words[0], Float.parseFloat(words[i]));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(table);

}
```

Txt File Sample:
[image]

The file can be found in the following link:
https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

Download the file

> glove.6B.zip

and open the

> glove.6B.50d.txt

text file.

Comment: If your code is throwing exceptions, you best bet is to step through program execution in your debugger. This should help you identify the bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason you are getting "Array out of Bound" exception is because you are splitting the strings by "\t\t" double tab space. whereas there are only single space. Due to this, each line is not being divided into multiple words but as 1 whole string and  and you are getting only 1 length array.

```
 String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split("\t\t");
// words.length will return 1, since it contains only single String( Whole line).
```

Replacing `split("\t\t")` with `split(" ")`, should fix the problem.By the way, there are total of 51 words in each line(if you include Starting words in each line). So you should `i < 51 not i <50`.

```
  for(i = 1; i < 51; i++){
     // Do your work...
    }

  //  i is starting from 1st index because at 0th index, the starting word will be placed and the floating points starts from 1st index.
```

However,as  @Satish Thulva has point out,there is still some problem with your code.The way your are doing with HashMap, the key(word) will have only last floating value( not the whole floating value in the line) as it value.
For ex,

```
truecar.com  -0.23163  0.39098  -0.7428  1.5123  -1.2368  -0.89173  -0.051826  -1.1305  0.96384  -0.12672  -0.8412  -0.76053  0.10582  -0.23173  0.11274  0.26327  0.053071  0.66657  0.9423  -0.78162  1.6225  0.097435  -0.67124  0.46235  0.3226  1.3423  0.87102  0.2217  -0.068228  0.73468  -1.0692  -0.85722  -0.49683  -1.4468  -1.1979  -0.49506  -0.36319  0.53553  -0.046529  1.5829  -0.1326  -0.55717  -0.17242  0.99214  0.73551  -0.51421  0.29743  0.19933  0.87613  0.63135
```

In your case, the result will be

```
 Key: truecar.com  value: 0.63135
```

To store all the floating values as `Value` for `key`, use `HashMap<String, Float[]>`

```
String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(" "); // split space between word and float number embedding

        //An Array of Float which will keep values for words.
        Float values[] = new Float[ words.length-1 ];    //  because we are not going to store word as its value.
        for( int i=1; i< words.length; i++){
            values[i-1] = Float.parseFloat(words[i]) ; }

        // Now all the values are stored in array.
        // Now store it in the Map.
        table.put(words[0], values);
```

Comment: One more thing. The `table` will contain only one `float` value for each `key`. Only the last one of the 50. The original poster should change that too. May be you can edit your answer to include that too :)

Comment: I forgot that part,thanks for pointing out. For this case we can pass no of parts the string should be divided into. i.e split(" ", 2).

Comment: Apparently, the text file has more than 51 data types in each line. Would that be a problem when reading and storing the keys and values in the HashMap? Is it possible to passed those values to the HashMap without knowing the exact columns and rows in my text file?

Comment: Yes,its possible but the problem here is that each key must be unique. when you try to add new floating point value, it will replace oider ones.So to overcome this problem, instead of using HashMap<String , FLoat>, use HashMap<String Float[]>

Comment: I have updated my answer (add the case if you do not know exact column and rows)